# .htaccess mod_rewrite regex for https server port

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

My website uses an external authentication service, which directs the user away from the desired page, performs the login, and then redirect back.

The trouble is when a user is redirected from an https page, the authentication service (which I cannot modify) stupidly redirects back to http:// with a :443 appended to the end of the URL, which just throws an error from Apache.

I already have an htaccess directive to ensure that the user is always viewing the current page on https:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

What I'm looking for is a rewrite rule that will detect a URL starting with http, and ending in :443, and then have it redirect to https:// without the port being appended.

I had tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

But that doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your .htaccess code with this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This rule will redirect all http traffic to https irrespective of any port being used with http requests.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. If I refresh the errored page it does not redirect. I think as the authetication script is redirecting to a specific URL on port 443, this isn't being caught.

Comment: but even with 443 it will still be http and `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` will return true. Try to test in a different browser or clear the cache.

Comment: What is your Apache server version?